# How to run multiple instance of PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I wants to run a multiple instance of one powershell script for multiple service with different parameter. I have written below powershell script , but not sure what i am doing its not taking parameter.

```
    [string[]] $ScriptstrArray = ‘-command Invoke-Expression ".\Smoke-Test.ps1 -Environment QA -servicename rpms"' ,
   ‘-command Invoke-Expression ".\Smoke-Test.ps1 -Environment QA - servicename rsms"' ,
  ‘-command Invoke-Expression ".\Smoke-Test.ps1 -Environment pvs - servicename spsms"'

workflow RunSmokeTests {
########################################################################
param([string[]]$sList)
    ForEach -Parallel ($s in $sList) {
       start-process powershell.exe -argument $s
    }
}

 RunSmokeTests -sList $ScriptstrArray
```

Can someone please me to identify the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any Errors? What did you try so far? Looks like only syntax or substitution issues could occur.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the external helper `Invoke-Parallel` for such scenarios in the past. It has a `-InputObject` parameter that allows you to pass in an array with e.g. the servers/services and their corresponding details. See [here](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel) or [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-Parallel-Parallel-377fd430) for source and examples.